# Scala, Akka-http - how to handle dynamic number of parameters?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I have a simple Akka routes:

```
    pathPrefix("api/games") {
      parameters("id".as[String].optional, "name".as[String].optional, "type".as[String].optional ...) { (id, name, type) => { 
       get {...}
     }
   }
 }
```

The problem is - I can have different number of optional parameters here. I do not want to pass all of them, because client can send different params. What is the best way to handle them dynamically (based on number of params) in akka-http?

I thought I can add all of them to list and check which are not `None`:

```
val params = List(id, name, type ...)
```

But I think it is very naive.

Comment: Are all optional strings?

Comment: Yes. All of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`parameterMap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMap.html) may be helpful in your case. It extracts all parameters as `Map[String, String]`. Or [`parameterMultiMap`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/directives/parameter-directives/parameterMultiMap.html) if some parameter may repeat.

Comment: You will be making some trade-offs here of course. Enlisting all parameterss what you presented as a naive approach isn't bad per se.

Comment: But what if I would need different type of parameters (not onyl Strings)?

Comment: You need to list the parameters with types somewhere in some form anyway. Another possible approach: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/case-class-extraction.html or consider generating routes out of the docs https://guardrail.dev/